# CRUD Excelsheets using Javascript for creation Automation Framework with Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, automation, protractor

I have worked with Selenium in creating framework for Quality Automation Testing. This was having separate files for Test Cases(Excelsheets file format), Object Map (XML format), ec.

My company has started using AngularJS and I am thinking of creating a similar Quality Automation framework using Protractor.

Since, Protractor is based on Javascript, I am wondering 
1. If I can read an excel file using Javascript ?
2. Whats the best way to do so ?
I read few online forums, blogs asking is it server side or client side; suggesting various things like converting it to XML, JSON, blah blah. Also, I found [JS XLS](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xls) and [JS XLSX](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx). Its all confusing and wanted insights into this with clear perspective of its use with Protractor / Javascript.

Thanks for your help, suggestions and advices.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please do it like below to read xlsx file via javascript for automating angular based websites using protractor (for more info plz visit `https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx`)

This is my first js file with name excelReader.js

```
var excelReader =  function(){
if(typeof require !== 'undefined')XLSX = require("../path/xlsx"); // path for xlxs directory that you have downloaded via npm
var workbook = XLSX.readFile("C:\\Users\\path\\Desktop\\nameofexcel.xlsx");
var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
this.Reader = function(cellValue){
    var address_of_cell = cellValue;
    var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
    var desired_cell = worksheet[address_of_cell];
    var desired_value = desired_cell.v;
    return desired_value;
};
}
    module.exports = new excelReader();
```

and in main test you can use it like below (i have used jasmine data provider)

```
var DataProvider = require("../path/excelReader.js"); // call the excelReader.js file
var using = require("../path/jasmine-data-provider"); // calling jasmine data provoider if u want u can leave it.
    describe("you text suite",function(){
    var dataProvider = {
                "Case 1 : Valid username and Invalid password" : {UN : DataProvider.Reader("C2"),PWD : DataProvider.Reader("D2")}, // C2 and D2 are excel cell value 
                };
        using(dataProvider, function(Parameter, description) {
            xit("your spec file(login example) " + description,function(){
                LoginPage.UserName(Parameter.UN); // here i have called the excel value which contains username and password
                LoginPage.Password(Parameter.PWD);
                LoginPage.SignIn();
            });
        });
    });
```

hope this helps you in case of any query plz ask.